# Assign Value , left side can not be assigned

Tags: delphi

A question on Delphi coding style . **I'm using a class class(TList< >) derived** from TList for working with functions y=f(x) ;

```
 TCurve = class(TList<TPointF>)
  private
  ....
  end;
```

the code goes now like this

```
 AnalysisCurve: TCurve;
```

and I want to increase the y value at a certain index  with this statement

```
AnalysisCurve.Items[i].y := AnalysisCurve.Items [ i ].y +1  ;
```

This does not work , I get an compiler error (
[dcc64 Error] -> E2064) , can not assign left side.
Can I assign a y value to the items in my list directly, without creating a TPointF variable and assign this var to my Tlist

```
testPt : TPointF; 

     testPt :=  AnalysisCurve.Items [i];

     testPt.y := testPt.Y  +1 ;

     AnalysisCurve.Items [ i] := testPt   ;
```

This code above works,  but I want to know why the first version fails.

Comment: [dcc64 Error]  ->   E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to;  also AnalysisCurve[ i ].Y  :=     4;  does not compile   and I use   TCurve = class(TList<TPointF>)  not only Curve=TList<TPointF>

Comment: @user1769184: Irrelevant, the root cause is the same. Your question simply has an extra attribute access.